# How to prove whether these two equations are satisfied at the same time?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I want to prove whether both $2p-m$ and $p+m$ are the multiples of $3$, where $p,m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

My solution:

Assume $2p-m = 3k$ and $2q-n = 3l$, where $k,l \in \mathbb{Z}$. So I could get $m = 2l-k$ and $p = k+l$. But I do not know how to prove whether above conditions must be satisfied at the same time. Could anyone help me out?

More specifically, if $p$ and $m$ are integers, $p \in [-N,N]$ and $m \in [-M,M]$. Is the answer the same? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well they don't *have* to be multiples of $3$, (if $p = 5;m=2$ then $2*5 -2$ and $5 + 2$ are not).  So what exactly are you asking? Are you trying to prove that either both are or are not multiples of $3$?

Comment: @fleablood Yes, exactly I am trying to prove either both are or are not multiples of $3$. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your question exactly?

1) $2p - m$ and $p +m$ are either both divisible by $3$ or neither are.

Divide $2p - m$ by three and you get a quotient, call it $q_1$ and you get a remainder, call it $r_1$, so that  $2p -m  = 3q_1 + r_1$

Divide $p+m$ by three and you get a quotient, call it $q_2$ and you get a remainder, call it $r_2$, so that  $p+m  = 3q_2 + r_2$

So $(2p - m) + (p+m) = 3p$ is divisible by three.  But $(2p-m) + (p+m) = (3q_1 + r_1) + (3q_2 + r_2) = 3(q_1 + q_2) + (r_1 + r_2)$.  So either $r_1 + r_2=0$  or $r_1 + r_2 = 3$.

If $r_1= 0$ then $r_2=0$ and both are divisible by $3$.

If $r_1= 1$ or $r_1 = 2$ then $r_2 =2$ or $r_1 = 1$ and neither are divisible by $3$.

Was that your question?

2)  If $2p - m$ and $p +m$ are both divisible by $3$ then the remainder of $p$ when divided by $3$ is the "opposite" of the remainder when $m$ is divided by $3$, in other words, if the remainder of $p$ is $k$ then the remainder of $m$ is $j= 3-k$ if $k \ne 0$ or it is $j = k = 0$ if $k = 0$.

If $m = 3q_3 + r_3$ and $m= 3q_4 + r_4$ then $2p -m = 2(3q_4 + r_4) - (3q_3 + r_3)= 3(2q_4 - q_3) + (2r_4 -r_3)$ so $2r_4 - r_3 = 0$ or $2r_4 - r_3 = 3$

And $p + m = 3q_4 + r_4 + 3q_3 + r_3 =3(q_4 + q_3) + (r_4 + r_3)$ so $r_4 + r_3 = 0$ or $r_4 + r_3 = 3$.

If $r_4 = 0$ then $r_3 = 0$.

If $r_4 =1$ then $r_3=2$.

If $r_4 = 2$ then $r_3 =1$.

Was that your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the detailed explanation! And there exists a typo: it should be $p = 3q_4+r_4$

Answer (score 1):

I do not get exactly your question but it could only be these two cases:

*a. Are you asking how to set up satisfying equation that generalize those two equations (assuring that both were satisfied simultaneously)?*

Well if that is the case then just do the modular arithmetic:

$$(2p-m)(p+m) (mod 9) = 0$$

*b. Are you asking how to set up a solution so that both relation holds?*

Well you also make use of modular arithmetic. First let us assume that the first relation holds. That is:
$$(2p-m) (mod3) = 0$$

Implying that, $$2p (mod3) = m$$

Now we multiply the second relation $p+m$ by 2 to get:
$$2(p+m)$$ and this new relation should also be divisible by 3:
$$(2p + 2m) (mod3)= (m+2m)(mod3) = 3m  (mod3) = 0$$

Hence, whenever $2p-m$ is divisible by $3$, so thus $p+m$!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am stating exactly the case b. Why the *first relation holds* means $2p - m(mod3) = 0$? Why not $(2p - m)(mod3) = 0$ ?

Comment: Its the same thing. What I meant was $(2p-m)(mod3)=0$

Comment: Thanks. I have another issue: Why do you multiply $p+m$ by $2$? And it seems that you miss something in the middle equation in the last step (no mod?)

Comment: We multiplied to get $2p$ since we know beforehand the characteristic of $2p$ and that is if we divide it by 3 the remainder is $m$.

Comment: I understand $2p(mod3) = m$, but why $(2p+2m)(mod3) = (p+m)(mod3)$? In fact, they are different.

Comment: On which part I have said that? I think you misunderstood me.

Comment: The part: *Now we multiply the second relation $p+m$ by $2$ to get*. I want to know whether $p+m(mod3) = 2p-m(mod3)$, instead of $2(p+m)$. But why do you multiply $p+m$ by $2$?

Comment: We multiply $2(p+m)$ because that product will only be divisible by $3$ when $(p+m)$ is divisible by $3$ since $2<3$. Is this the part you want me to expound or provide proof?